Automatically start debugging sub-process only when started from VS-TestExplorer
I have written a testadapter that mainly starts another process and delegates executing my unit-tests in that process. So in fact my adapter is just the bridge between vstest-host and my other process. Let's call that process MyProcess.exe.
Now I want to start debugging my tests in that process. However when using VS-text-explorer, the debugger immediately attaches to the vstest-host-process (testhost.net472.x86.exe in my case). What I want instead is to attch the debugger when MyProcess.exe spins up. So effetivly I want to skip jumping into the host-process when debugging, but instead directly debug MyProcess.exe.
So this is my workflow:
VS Test Explorer --> Debug unit-test
  --> new testhost-process
  --> debugger is attached to testhost-process
  --> start MyProcess.exe within my adapter
      --> debug MyProcess.exe instead of testhost

Of course I can manually attach to the process. But then the debugger is either attached to two processes, or I need a second instance of VS running, which I both find odd. I also tried to add a Debugger.Launch in my own process. However that assumes a further user-interaction, while I actually already indicated that I want to debug my tests. So this is kind of doubled. Also this doesn't allow me, to not attach a debugger when only running the tests or when just running MyProcess.exe outside of VS.

If you have elevated permission you can set automatically debug your subprocess automatically in registry and here are the steps:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/a329t4ed(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

@AmadeuszLiu That's not exactly my need. I want to differ between being in VS and chosing "debug tests in TestExplorer" where I want the debugger to start automatically, and "run the tests in TestExplorer" or even "start the process outside of VS".

Then you may have already mentioned the best approach in your question description as you are debugging on tests in multiple processes.I'm afraid using
Debugger.Launch() could be the current best option.

Inspired by the code from here https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/tree/main/src/AttachVS I was able to attach the already running VS to my own process. So in my adapter I am calling the following code:
public void RunTests(IEnumerable<TestFixtureWrapper> fixtures, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
{
    var process = // get the process you want to debug
    if(runContext.IsBeingDebugged)
    {
         DebuggerUtility.AttachVSToProcess(process.Id, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
    }
    // ... do something
}

This will attach the debugger only when you're already within a debug-session when the adapters Run-method is called by vstest. The only drawback is, that you're still attached to two processes. But at least you don't need to manually attach.
